# How do I deploy a Lazarus pascal app on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, lazarus

Here's what I did:

1. I created a simple Lazarus app on Windows. It uses a sqlite3 db, with the DatabaseName specified in the code. It works fine on Win.
2. I compiled the same source code on Mac OS (same version of Lazarus; Yosemite). App runs fine from IDE.
3. Double clicking the resulting Project.App bundle produces an error. The DBConnection component is unable to open the database file. In fact FileExists(myDBfile) returns false here.

How do I put everything together to create this simple app to distribute to others?

p.s. It's probably obvious, but I am brand new to the OS X world.

Comment: guessing: File paths / config? Whatever you do - the file information for where to find stuff is going to be different between the two environments? You do need to know what environment you are running under and set the filepaths accordingly? The standalone exe has to use the current environment settings / paths. The IDE sets it all up for you when it runs the exe.

Comment: Thanks, @Ryan. I did not realize OSX was specific about where supporting db's, images, etc. needed to be located.

Comment: also watch out for forward-slash v back-slash